# How to hide parameters such as APIKey from Jenkins pipeline console output

Tags: linux, shell, unix, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I hide certain parameters or **** them when I execute scripts inside stage.

The command that is producing the output which I want to hide is:

```
sh "./wsagent_execute.sh -s -apiKey ${WHITESOURCE_API_KEY} -projectToken ${WHITESOURCE_PROJECT_TOKEN} -C ${configPath} -d ${directoryPath} -logLevel info"
```

The parameters I want to hide are -apiKey and -projectToken. How can I do it?

Comment: You would need to assign them as environment variables and resolve them in the shell interpreter instead of within Groovy. However, you have two Groovy variables in your string, so it would not be possible for what you are trying to do.

Comment: this is inside the pipeline code inside the stage step inside the script tag. Jenkins builds this pipeline so there's no shell interpreter involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get your credentials from a vault, you can use Mask Passwords plugin. It does not state that it supports Pipelines but actually it does.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
      stage('doing something') {
        steps {
          script {
            def current_nano = "1616407597607795668"
            sh label: "Now you see it", script: "echo ${current_nano}"
            maskPasswords(varPasswordPairs: [[password: current_nano, var: 'IGNORE']]) {
              sh label: "Now you don't", script: "echo ${current_nano}"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (doing something)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh (Now you see it)
+ echo 1616407597607795668
1616407597607795668
[Pipeline] maskPasswords
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh (Now you don't)
+ echo ********
********
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // maskPasswords
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: I tried you steps but it gives me an error : No such DSL method 'maskPasswords' found among steps

Comment: You need to install the plugin in order to use its methods.

Comment: hey it worked but using the wrap since it was declarative. Also can you add more than one variable to mask

Comment: You can: `varPasswordPairs: [[password: current_nano, var: 'IGNORE'], [password: '1234', var: "IGNORE2"],[password: 'hunter2', var: 'IGNORE3']]`

Answer (score 0):

Are these keys calculated in the pipeline or are they statics?
You can try to use it like credentials in Jenkins and you don't see their values in the log.

Comment: these keys are defined in the environment part of the pipeline. ProjectToken is from the PipelineParams argument and APIToken is from vault: path ....

How can I use these as credentials since they're define differently

Comment: You can't use Jenkins credential to store it, obviusly.

Answer (score -1):

If you use a secret define in Jenkins credential, Jenkins will automatically mask that for you and in the log, it will show as ****

let's say you have defined your apiKey in jenkins credential with Id: apikey. Than you can use that on your pipeline like below example.

more details can be found [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/)

```
node() {
   withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'apikey', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
      sh "./wsagent_execute.sh -s -apiKey $TOKEN -projectToken ${WHITESOURCE_PROJECT_TOKEN} -C ${configPath} -d ${directoryPath} -logLevel info"
   }
}
```

If you are not happy with that use [mask password](https://plugins.jenkins.io/mask-passwords/) or something similar plugins